# Unbound Subform with Multiple Link Filters?

Tags: sql, ms-access, filter, vba

I have a sub form tied to a table.  This table has a foreign key, which holds the key to different tables, depending on the value.  Based on the value, the information in the record is tied to a certain object level in the schema.  It may be tied to the main record based on the main entry form.  It may be tied to another subform record, etc.

So let's say the main form is for projects.  For each project they could be placed into many buildings.  Within each building they may have multiple staff.  This somewhat inter-dependent sub form is for project documents.  They may relate to the current project.  They can also relate to one of the buildings for the current project, but only for that current project.  Or the document could relate to one of the buildings, but for all projects.  I already have a combo that gets it's row source based on the relationship type/doc type combo that is chosen first.  That let's the user choose the actual building, staff or whatever the doc is related to.

I need to create a filter for the sub form that will give all records related to that main record and/or it's sub records, and still be able to add new records.  I've been looking at a case statement, but concerned that will only apply the first true case.  I was thinking of a union, but guessing I won't be able to add records.  It won't be updateable.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Without a better idea of the schema, it's difficult to suggest an appropriate query/filter. Also, are you presenting multiple records in the subform? If this is unable to be edited, how about another subform specifically for editing?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  I ended up creating 2 sub forms.  One for viewing all records that are somehow tied to the main record.  This has a record source set to a union view, with a where clause for the main record ID.  The second form is for adding/editing new records and the record source is tied to the documents table, with a filter to the record being edited, or the data entry set to yes, for adding new records.  This is all set based on a toggle button, new main record activity, etc.